# Неслучайность младших битов

Tags: c, генерация-случайных-данных

Нужно получить последовательность из миллиона чисел согласно алгоритму, описанному Д. Кнутом в его книге "Искусство программирования".
Формула: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все числа в данной последовательности на самом деле не случайны, так как самый младший бит, отвечающий за чётность, просто чередуется.
Вопрос: как это можно исправить?

```
// Участок кода с генерацией последовательности:
 unsigned long long m = 4294967296; 
    unsigned long long c = 397284255;  
    unsigned long long a = 3178274045;    
 srand(__rdtsc() % m);
    numbers[0] = rand() % m;

for (i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {

        numbers[i] = ((numbers[i - 1] * a) + c) % m;
}
```

Comment: А откуда взяты константы? Насколько я помню, `m` рекомендовано выбирать простым, нет?

Comment: m = 2^32, т.е. длине машинного слова. При такой длине будет максимально большой период. Остальные константы подобраны исходя из тех же соображений

Comment: Посмотрите, что пишет Кнут. Он этот вопрос точно разбирает. Не верите Кнуту - посмотрите в Википедии. Учтите, что выбор большого `m` не гарантирует большой период! А четный `m` - это вообще, гм... словом, именно четность и обеспечивает вам чередование младшего бита. Словом, читайте книжек...